# Fitting a regression model

Tags: statistics, regression

I'm trying to solve a question from a Chinese "linear statistical models",
and the chapter containing this question is about weighted least squares.

The question and the way I solve it are as following:

[image]

As you can see, the predicted values is very different to the actual value, so I wonder about whether I solve it right or not.

Could somebody tell me what is wrong with it?
And if there are mistakes how I correct it?

Comment: You would get a better response if you asked on http://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank you, I will try to ask there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The predicted values are actually not that far off from the actual values. This seems fine and a seems like a sensible result here